# Split Wave audio file at silence

Tags: java, audio, split, wav, javasound

I have a bunch human reading simple sentence (hello world) as a wav file.

- How can I break the wav file for 2 wav files each contains word (hello and world) by automatically recognizing the gap between the words?
- Can I do this in Java?

If yes please show me the way.

PS. the gap is silent (not noise) , the Wav file is mono type